# How to handle multi response data to built a frequency in Python 3?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I am using a multiple response data set to built some frequency table using python panda.
Here is my data set:

```
Student Id  |1st_Lang   |2nd_Lang   |Core_Sub_1 |Core_Sub_2 |Core_Sub_3 |Additional
1       |Bengali    |English    |Math       |Life Sc    |Physical Sc    |Work Education
2       |Bengali    |English    |Geography  |Life Sc    |Physical Sc    |Physical Education
3       |Bengali    |English    |History    |Geography  |Economics  |Life Sc
4       |English    |Hindi      |History    |Geography  |Economics  |Life Sc
5       |Hindi      |English    |Math       |Life Sc    |Physical Sc    |Work Education
```

A sample student data having Student Id and different subjects they have chosen as language, core and additional.

I want to generate the frequency of subjects are being studied by students

**Example:**

```
English - 5
Bengali - 3
Hindi - 2
Geography - 3
... etc.
```

also I want to get frequency of subjects are being studied by students where language studied by students are English or Hindi (from 1st_lang, 2nd_Lang columns).

Please can you help to be done it using Python?

Comment: welcome to SO! When asking a question, please consider providing what you have tried so far with some sample code, etc. Even better, before asking a question here, search for similar questions asked in the past that might help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because we don't need it, we drop the 'Student Id' aside as index (or drop it):

```
df= df.set_index("Student Id")
#df= df.drop(columns=""Student Id")

           1st_Lang 2nd_Lang Core_Sub_1 Core_Sub_2   Core_Sub_3          Additional
Student Id
1           Bengali  English       Math    Life Sc  Physical Sc      Work Education
2           Bengali  English  Geography    Life Sc  Physical Sc  Physical Education
3           Bengali  English    History  Geography    Economics             Life Sc
4           English    Hindi    History  Geography    Economics             Life Sc
5             Hindi  English       Math    Life Sc  Physical Sc      Work Education
```

Stacking the df, we got a Series (with MultiIndex):

```
ser= df.stack()

Student Id
1           1st_Lang                 Bengali
            2nd_Lang                 English
            Core_Sub_1                  Math
            Core_Sub_2               Life Sc
            Core_Sub_3           Physical Sc
            Additional        Work Education
2           1st_Lang                 Bengali
            2nd_Lang                 English
            Core_Sub_1             Geography
            Core_Sub_2               Life Sc
            Core_Sub_3           Physical Sc
            Additional    Physical Education
3           1st_Lang                 Bengali
            2nd_Lang                 English
            Core_Sub_1               History
            Core_Sub_2             Geography
            Core_Sub_3             Economics
            Additional               Life Sc
4           1st_Lang                 English
            2nd_Lang                   Hindi
            Core_Sub_1               History
            Core_Sub_2             Geography
            Core_Sub_3             Economics
            Additional               Life Sc
5           1st_Lang                   Hindi
            2nd_Lang                 English
            Core_Sub_1                  Math
            Core_Sub_2               Life Sc
            Core_Sub_3           Physical Sc
            Additional        Work Education
dtype: object
```

We can now count the frequencies:

```
ser.value_counts()

Life Sc               5
English               5
Physical Sc           3
Bengali               3
Geography             3
Work Education        2
Hindi                 2
Math                  2
History               2
Economics             2
Physical Education    1
dtype: int64
```

Now look at the Hindi learning students, set the criteria:

```
critH= df[["1st_Lang","2nd_Lang"]].eq("Hindi")

            1st_Lang  2nd_Lang
Student Id
1              False     False
2              False     False
3              False     False
4              False      True
5               True     False
```

We count Hindi as the 1st and as the 2nd language, too:

```
critH=critH.any(axis=1)

Student Id
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```

Selects the matching rows(students) and count the frequencies in one step:

```
df.loc[critH].stack().value_counts()

Life Sc           2
Hindi             2
English           2
History           1
Work Education    1
Math              1
Economics         1
Physical Sc       1
Geography         1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks Kantal for the solution. It works fine. I have a further query for large number data columns having additional single response data (for example total marks, roll no, address, class, etc.) - will the stack work properly? What would you suggest? Please help.

Comment: It may work, but it is better to present tha data, and even better to ask a new question.